# How to calculate a year to date subtotal in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table like this:

```
2019.03m Bolts  100
2019.03m Nuts    50
2019.02m Bolts   10
2019.02m Nuts   100 
2019.01m Bolts   50
2019.01m Nuts    10
2018.12m Bolts   10
2018.12m Nuts    10
2018.11m Bolts   20
2018.11m Nuts    30
```

I would like to introduce a new column called the year to date column

```
2019.03m Bolts  100 160
2019.03m Nuts    50 160
2019.02m Bolts   10  60
2019.02m Nuts   100 110 
2019.01m Bolts   50  50
2019.01m Nuts    10  10
2018.12m Bolts   10  30
2018.12m Nuts    10  40
2018.11m Bolts   20  20
2018.11m Nuts    30  30
```

This sums the previous year-to-date row and resets when it reaches a new year.

I have an idea of using `sums` but how can I reset when I get to a new year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the below is what you are after. Note I have reversed the table in order put in time ascending order initially.

```
reverse  update YTD:sums Number  by tool,date.year from reverse t

date    tool  Number YTD
------------------------
2019.03 Bolts 100    160
2019.03 Nuts  50     160
2019.02 Bolts 10     60
2019.02 Nuts  100    110
2019.01 Bolts 50     50
2019.01 Nuts  10     10
2018.12 Bolts 10     30
2018.12 Nuts  10     40
2018.11 Bolts 20     20
2018.11 Nuts  30     30
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is ordered by date(descending in your example) you can use below query. Else you can just order it using `date xdesc` before running the query.

```
q) update ytd:reverse sums reverse num by date.year,name from t
```